# CSS, vertical delimeter between inline-block buttons(links)

Tags: html, css

I have few button and want to add vertical delimeter(separator) between 'Button 1' and 'Button 2'. I understand that can wrap my link in div with border:

```
<div id="delimeterDiv" style="border-right: 1px solid #C0C0C0;">
</div>
```

but I want my links in one line. If I add another div it starts from another line..

Here is jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Rockietm/dtnwmdho/

Here is what I want to get:

[image: buttons]

and here is code:

```
<style>
        #buttons {
            margin-bottom: 12px;
            height: 46px;
        }

        #buttons > a {
            color: black;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-right: 15px;
            margin-top: 2px;
            font-size: large;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        /* button colors */
        #buttonone {
            background-color: #DCDCDC;
        }

        #buttontwo {
            background-color: #C4E2F3;
        }

        #buttonthree {
            background-color: #B2F0C8;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="buttons">
        <a id="buttonone" href="#" >Button 1</a>
        <a id="buttontwo" href="#">Button 2</a>
        <a id="buttonthree" href="#">Button 3</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `:after` to the button and style it to look like a border

```
#buttons > a:after {

       content:'';
       position:absolute;
       top: 0;
       right: -10px;
       height:100%;
       width: 1px;
       background: #000;

 }

 #buttons > a:last-child:after{
        width: 0;/*remove border from the last button*/
 }
```

[**See jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/dtnwmdho/2/)

Comment: Added it as an answer to complete yours wich works great too ;)

Comment: Oh, I can use :after.. Perfect! Thank You guys very much!

Answer (score 2):

Similar base for answer (pseudo + absolute) with a différent approach to complete @Chiller answer's.

```css
#buttons>a:first-child~a:before {
  content: '';
  border-left: double gray;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -12px;
}


}
#buttons {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  height: 46px;
}
#buttons>a {
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  font-size: large;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

/* button colors */
#buttonone {
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
}
#buttontwo {
  background-color: #C4E2F3;
}
#buttonthree {
  background-color: #B2F0C8;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
  <a id="buttonone" href="#">Button 1</a>
  <a id="buttontwo" href="#">Button 2</a>
  <a id="buttonthree" href="#">Button 3</a>
</div>
<!--buttons-->
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dtnwmdho/3/

Answer (score 1):

Should help you:

```
#buttons> a:first-child:after  {
   border-right: 1px solid black;
   content: " ";
   position: relative;
   right: -20px ;
   padding: 10px 0;        
}
```